# Why am I having trouble with the Android Emulator in VS Comm 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-emulator, runtime-error

I was having trouble using the Android emulator in Visual Studio Community 2017 and I decided to create a blank project to see if it will run. I get this error message when attempting to run it in the Live Xamarin Player:

```
Starting Android Emulator Android_Accelerated_x86_Nougat...
Failed to boot Android device emulator-5554...
Unable to deploy to Android_Accelerated_x86_Nougat, please ensure the Xamarin
Live Player app is open and the device is on the same network as Visual Studio.
```

Why would I have trouble running the emulator in a fresh blank project when I didn't even write a single line of code? Thanks for your help.

UPDATE: So I installed the latest Android SDK 8.0 along with they system image and tried to create a virtual device that uses it. But the Android Virtual Device Manager shows a, 'No system images installed' message when I selected the 8.0 framework. So I installed an earlier version of the SDK along with a system image (5) and was able to create a virtual device with it. So another question is why wouldn't the system images show up for the 8.0 framework?

Comment: OK, I discovered that in order to use the Xamarin Live Player you need to have an Android device with the Xamarin Live Player app installed. Then you scan a QR code to run the app. Isn't there a way to run an Android emulator in VS?

Comment: I get these warnings after trying to run the project:

    The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.dll (vv8.0) is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project (v7.1). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project. XamTestApp1.Android C:\...\XamTestApp1\XamTestApp1.Android\XamTestApp1.Android.csproj

Comment: I clicked on Tools->Get Tools and Features, and discovered that I have the "Google Android Emulator (API Level 25)" installed. And the description says that a separate device is not required to run and test my apps. So there is some other issue with running the emulator that I'm not understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though Google has gotten rid of the GUI apps that manage the SDK and Virtual Devices in the latest version, so when you try to create a new virtual device with 8.0 it's not compatible with the GUI tools. Until Xamarin releases a GUI tool to replace them we can use the command-line to manage the SDK and virtual devices.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/sdk-cli-tooling-changes

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/avdmanager.html

Answer (score 1):

> The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.dll
>   (vv8.0) is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project
>   (v7.1). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your
>   project

This means the Xamarin.Forms library is targeting Android 8.0 (API level 26) but your project is setup for Android 7.1 (API level 25). You can't change the Xamarin.Forms target version without downgrading, but you can change your project target version easily. You can learn more about these concepts from [Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/android-api-levels/). Be aware some of the details of that Xamarin blog post are already out of date!

There is another nice [blog post](https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-android-8-0-gets-even-sweeter-with-oreo/) from Xamarin which can walk you through the process of setting your system up for Android 8.0 API level 26. It's normally not this complicated, but Google changed their SDK tools internally between 25 and 26 in very major ways. They changed from GUI tools to command line tools.

You'll probably also want to get the (in preview) [Xamarin Android Device Manager](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/android-emulator/xamarin-device-manager/) if you don't have a physical device to test with. This Xamarin Android Device Manager tool is the only way to create and configure API 26 and higher emulators without using the Google command line tools.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, those links have really enlightened me to some things. But I'm still having trouble with the emulator. Instead of running my project into the emulator, I clicked on "Android Virtual Device Manager", selected an emulator and clicked Start. That's when I receive this error:

Comment: Starting emulator forAVD 'AVD_GalaxyNexus_ToolsForApacheCordova'
    emulator: WARNING: Crash service did not start
    ERROR: resizing partition e2fsck failed with exit code 8
emulator: WARNING: Classic qemu does not support SMP. The hw.cpu.ncore option from your config file is ignored.

Comment: And then the emulator stays stuck on the black screen with the words Android on it.